# цикличность срабатывания .load

Tags: php, javascript

В начале загрузки страницы нужно получить данные в js из php:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result").load('XXX.php',function(data){
 // здесь исользуется полученная data
    });
    
    // тут продолжение всевозможного кода
    
  });
</script>
```

В вышеуказанном виде запрос в XXX.php идет циклично (беспрерывно). Я понимаю да, что к запросу нужно привязать событие. Но какое может событие в самом начале загрузки страницы?

Comment: выясняйте, что вызывает повторяющиеся запросы к `'XXX.php'`. У Вас страница случайно не перегружается все время?

Comment: Это вариант. Если, например? в файле-обработчике XXX.php  header('location',..); присутствует.

Comment: @VitVlad ___Но какое может событие в самом начале загрузки?___ - по временному интервалу как вариант.

Comment: Kirill Korushkin,

Comment: Спасибо всем кто ответил. Думал, что без события метод постоянно прокручивается... Код до обновления отлично работал, поэтому был уверен в уже написанном. Спасибо Igor еще раз перебрал где идет обновление странички. Дело в том что у меня код проверяет входящую информацию и где есть подозрение на нехорошие вливания скидывает значение и обновляет страницу. "Утро вечера мудренее" Эдуард приведи пожалуйста пример - интересно на будущее.